# Flux simulator genome data processing

Tags: bioinformatics, fasta, genome

I am working on converting genome/gtf data to FASTA file format. I am using flux-simulator for that. The demo example from the flux-simulator works without any problem.
After that, I downloaded genome and gtf data from http://hgdownload.soe.ucsc.edu/downloads.html, https://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTables?command=start.

But while running mouse(mm9) gtf, it does not work at all and shows the error: 
[ERROR] Error while loading stats: Field 5 not found
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field 5 not found

I also tried to run flux simulator for "fly" genome.

I got this error:
[INFO] Loading default PCR distribution
        preparing transcript sequences ** ERROR
[ERROR] Error while preparing sequences:
[ERROR] Error while fragmenting : Problems reading sequence chr2L: pos 22877860, len 82,
check whether chromosomal sequence exists / has the correct size
java.lang.RuntimeException: Problems reading sequence chr2L: pos 22877860, len 82,

Can you please tell how to solve these problems?

Comment: Can you please prepare a more specific case where you encounter a problem. For instance, specific and small subset of the GTF file that produces the error, and the exact command line used. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for help.

Comment: The command line command: /homes/username/flux-simulator-1.2.1/bin/flux-simulator -p example.par